# Archiving not works

Tags: postgresql, wal

I've setup the WAL archiving already and when I'm running the following query,
`SELECT * FROM pg_stat archiver;` The system gives me back this:

> Archived count 0, last_archived_wal (empty), last_archived_time (empty), failed_count, 40 (keep growing), last_failed_wal (lot of numbers, always same), and the fail time and stat reset.

The log file:

2023-01-13 00:01:37.846 JST [5456] LOG: archive command failed with exit code 1 2023-01-13 00:01:37.846 JST [5456] DETAIL: The failed archive command was: copy "pg_wal\000000010000002300000063" "C:\server\archivedir\000000010000002300000063" 2023-01-13 00:01:37.848 JST [5456] WARNING: archiving write-ahead log file "000000010000002300000063" failed too many times, will try again later The system cannot find the path specified.

The psql create the files, 16 MB each and also create the .ready files. Bit when I like to check the status ( SELECT * FROM pg_stat_archiver; )

Comment: Look at the PostgreSQL server log file. It will contain the error message.

Comment: Checked but not clear. I do this step by step and not works always how error. Made the 16 MB files but count errors. 
https://orahow.com/enable-disable-archive-mode-in-postgres/

Comment: Stop and think. You are asking a question and want help. But all you give us is that "it does not work" and "the log file entries are not clear". If you want a better answer than "do it right, then it will work", you should share some of that information.